# Populate child field to Parent field

Tags: apex, trigger

A parent Object i.e `Monitoring_Device__c` and one child i.e `Performance_Forecast__c`. there is one field on child i.e `Deviation_Percentage__c`.. I have  to calculate total deviation every month and to display total on parent object field i.e `Average_Deviation__c`.. I m Attaching my Code here

```
if(trigger.isInsert) {
        try{
            for (Performance_Forecast__c  cp : Trigger.new){
                Monitoring_Device__c  objDevice = [SELECT Id, Average_Deviation__c FROM Monitoring_Device__c  WHERE Id = :cp.Monitoring_Device__c ];                 
                Decimal amount = 0.0;
                List<Performance_Forecast__c> l_cp = [SELECT Id, Deviation_Percentage__c, Month__c FROM Performance_Forecast__c  WHERE Monitoring_Device__c = :objDevice.Id];
                //integer Average = l_cp.size();
                for(Performance_Forecast__c  am_cp : l_cp) {
                   amount += am_cp.Deviation_Percentage__c ;  

                }
                //amount = amount/Average ;
                objDevice.Average_Deviation__c = amount;
                update objDevice ;

            }
        }catch (Exception e)  {
            system.debug(e);
        }
    }
```

i m able to do the total and display it on parent but when i m changing one of the record from child its not getting update on Parent field...

Comment: Queries and DML inside a for loop is a bad practice. Looks like you might be having the trigger on Parent object, which would only fire when you updated the parent record.

Comment: Your trigger will only run during an Insert, see `if(trigger.isInsert)` at the top, so nothing will change incase of any change in record. Plus what Rahul said is valid, SOQL inside a for loop is not a good practice.

Answer (score 0):

As was posted in the comment by Santanu Halder, you state that you are updating a child record and not seeing the field update you expect on the parent record - but your trigger logic is wrapped in a block which says

```
if (trigger.isInsert)
```

...and so the calculation will only be made and the field updated when a new child record is inserted.

If all the logic in this trigger should be run when a child record is updated, then you could remove this condition block altogether.

Alternatively, if some of the logic **should** only run on new records, then you'll need to restructure some/all of your trigger and ensure that calculation of this field goes outside of the conditional block, or even in it's own block with a condition such as

```
if (trigger.isUpdate)
```

or

```
if (trigger.isUpdate || trigger.isInsert)
```